# Bash script to monitor log, match keyword then send commands, resume monitoring

Tags: linux, bash, logging, monitor

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo tail -fn0 /home/main/time.log |
grep -o --line-buffered 'garage\|garden\|porch' | head -1 |
    while read line; do 
sudo pkill -f porch.sh &
sudo pkill -f garage.sh &
done
```

I'm trying to write a script that monitors a log, and upon matching a keyword, it will fire off some commands.

Problem is, what I've pieced together will work only once, then exit and stop monitoring.

If multiple keywords appear in the tail at the same time, I want it to execute at the first keyword, ignore the rest of the keywords, execute the scripts listed, then go back to monitoring the tail of the log. I added "head -1" to grep to stop grep after the first match, but that also exits grep, so the script basiclly stops monitoring.

I would prefer the script to remain active after it matches a keyword and continue monitoring the tail of the log for any new keywords that might get logged.

Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52058293/edit) to include more information.  Could you give us an example of the line you want to trigger on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can be made a little more compact and a little more efficient but this long form will help in understanding, about what is going on:

So the basic idea is to monitor `/home/main/time.log` and check if the number of lines have changed in the file, if they have then we want to find out how many new rows were added, we will use this variable to tail the last n number of files and do a grep on them, as that is the condition required to run the kill processes.

```
touch last.keyfile

while true
do 
old_line=$(cat last.keyfile) 
n_lines=$(cat time.log | wc -l);echo $n_lines > last.keyfile 


if [ -z $old_line ];then

    old_line=$(echo "$n_lines")
fi

differ=$((n_lines-old_line))


if [[ $differ > 0 && $(tail -n"$differ" time.log | grep 'abc\|pub' | wc -l) > 0 ]];then   
echo yes

fi
sleep 5
done
```

P.S. : kindly make relevant changes before running.

Comment: Your solution looks fantastic, unfortunately I'm having trouble getting it to execute a command. I added the paths to my log, added keywords to grep, then added a command to execute after then statement. I tested by appending matching keywords to my log file through a terminal echo command. It does record the lines of text in the log file which I verified by checking last.keyfile, which accurately lists how many lines are in the log file. Unfortunately it won't execute the commands I added. Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks again for your time and expert advice!

Comment: @fizers sorry to hear that it didn't work I will recheck everything and make edits

Comment: @fizers I have made required edits, the problem was from two things one was use of `\` slash in grep other major problem was we were writing new number of lines before the old_line variable could read it causing the difference to be always zero. fixed that in the code

Comment: Thank you for the edits. Your solution is working brilliantly! Thanks again for your time and genius coding.!!

Comment: Better that u use inotifywait. also why sleep 5? u going to loose so many lines that were appear after.